# Custom 404 error page not displayed

Tags: servlets, web.xml, custom-error-pages

I have following configured in web.xml

```
<error-page>
        <error-code>404</error-code>
        <location>/errors/404.html</location>
</error-page>
```

And I have created a custom 400.html page.

When any resource is not found, I see a plain white page with "Not found" written on it, but I don't get to see my custom error page.

I also see following in the logs.

> WARNING [javax.enterprise.resource.webcontainer.jsf.application]
>   (default task-29) JSF1064: Unable to find or serve resource,
>   /harry.jsf

Comment: Thanks for pointing out, I corrected it. It was just the name of the page. The error-code parameter is 400 and that is correct.

Comment: No I copy pasted from editor. It is the same

Comment: Figured it out. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Just figured out I was missing the servlet-maaping 
I added following mapping and it is working now.

```
<servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```